# Nginx conflicts with multiple locations

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I have the follow configuration on Nginx.

```
location ~ (/website|/login) {
     #proxy to server A
     ...
 }

location /dashboard {
     #proxy to server B
     ....
}
```

The conflict occurs when a requests is done to `/dashboard/login`, it is entering on `server A` instead of `server B` that I desire.

A ugly solution that works perfectly:

```
location /website {
     #proxy to server A
     ...
 }

location /login {
     #proxy to server A
     ...
 }

location /dashboard {
     #proxy to server B
     ....
}
```

How can I change this configuration for /dashboard/login matches the #b definition?
I want to avoid repetitive code I used on ugly solution.

Comment: You're wrong about ugliness. The solution is simple and efficient while your original config is ugly and error-prone

Comment: To avoid self repetition use `include` directive

Answer (score 0):

Your "ugly" solution in fact is concise and clear. It doesn't involve regexp magic which may be hard to understand and modify.

> http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location
>
> <...> nginx first checks locations defined using the prefix strings. <...> Then regular expressions are checked, in the order of their appearance in the configuration file. The search of regular expressions terminates on the first match, and the corresponding configuration is used.

But here is solution with only two location blocks.

```
# Location order is important!

location ~ /dashboard {
     #proxy to server B
}

location ~ (/website|/login) {
     #proxy to server A
}
```

Comment: There are two better solutions. One: `location ^~ /dashboard { ... }`, second `location ~ ^(/website|/login) { ... }`

Comment: I think "ugly" solution still the best. :)